# Parrot OS no Wifi Applet/Can't COnnect

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, parrot-os

So I've just installed Parrot Security OS On my Dell XPS 9370 Which is running the following wifi chipset 02:00.0 Network controller: 
`Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)` However I'm unable to get wifi working at all on it. When I first login theres a popup which says wifi networks are available but clicking it does nothing. There doesn't seem to be a wifi applet either which shows available networks. I've tried downloading firmware online for the wifi chipset which hasn't solved the issue either.

Below are some syslogs which may indicate something to someone but not to me!

````
Jan 21 18:44:39 parrot kernel: [  355.053941] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Jan 21 18:44:39 parrot NetworkManager[835]: <info>  [1548096279.5974] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: ready -> disabled
Jan 21 18:44:39 parrot NetworkManager[835]: <info>  [1548096279.6158] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disabled -> inactive
Jan 21 18:44:39 parrot wpa_supplicant[834]: wlan0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Jan 21 18:47:46 parrot wpa_supplicant[834]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Jan 21 18:47:46 parrot NetworkManager[2293]: <info>  [1548096466.3396] wifi-nl80211: (wlan0): using nl80211 for WiFi device control
Jan 21 18:47:46 parrot wpa_supplicant[834]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Jan 21 18:47:46 parrot NetworkManager[2293]: <info>  [1548096466.5779] device (wlan0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
Jan 21 18:47:46 parrot NetworkManager[2293]: <info>  [1548096466.5784] manager: (wlan0): new 802.11 WiFi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
Jan 21 18:47:46 parrot NetworkManager[2293]: <info>  [1548096466.5796] device (wlan0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jan 21 18:47:46 parrot kernel: [  542.054412] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Jan 21 18:47:46 parrot NetworkManager[2293]: <info>  [1548096466.6670] device (wlan0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to F6:E2:57:AC:D5:BD (scanning)
Jan 21 18:47:47 parrot kernel: [  542.887547] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Jan 21 18:47:47 parrot NetworkManager[2293]: <info>  [1548096467.4225] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: init -> starting
Jan 21 18:47:47 parrot NetworkManager[2293]: <info>  [1548096467.5267] sup-iface[0x5612780340c0,wlan0]: supports 5 scan SSIDs
Jan 21 18:47:47 parrot NetworkManager[2293]: <info>  [1548096467.5289] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
Jan 21 18:47:47 parrot NetworkManager[2293]: <info>  [1548096467.5290] device (wlan0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 21 18:47:47 parrot kernel: [  543.003938] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready```
````

Comment: Okay so I believe I've found the issue, there is in fact a network applet Its just really hidden. I've got a 4k resolutin/high dpi display and the scaling that the OS Is doing isn't properly scaling the applets/notification area. So all the applets are squished together. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little late in coming but I scoured the webs for the same issue and your thread gave me the lead I needed.

Under the menu System->Preferences->Hardware->Displays you can set the resolution. I had to play with it for a bit for my network manager to show up. Weird that parrot doesn't deal with hi-res well.